# Android application distribution after Google App Signing

Tags: android, jenkins, google-play, android-app-signing

Now we can use "App Signing by Google play" to sign our apps and will not have to manage keystores. But we use Jenkins for build creation and then share it with customers for testing via HockeyApp.
**How can we integrate Google's App Signing along with Jenkins and HockeyApp for testing before actual release?**

Answer (score 2):

If you use Google App Signing, then the actual key to sign your app is only known by Google.  That doesn't prevent you from signing it with another key and distributing it elsewhere, but it does mean that if you do, your users won't be able to update that copy via Google Play.  If they're in a beta and supposed to be getting all the builds from a beta site, that's ok.

By the way Google Play also has beta functionality, it may be easier just to do the beta through them.